# Resize UITextView based on content and Font

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, uitextview

I am trying to resize a `UITextView` based on its content. The string i have inserted in, have a custom font.

My view is like this:

---

|                   |                                   |
|  UILabel 300px    |  UITextview 468px                 | 
|                   |                                   |

---

In the `ViewDidLoad` method, I have tried to resize the `UITextView` like this:

```
CGFloat textViewWidth = self.myTextView.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = self.myTextView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, textViewWidth), newSize.height);
self.myTextView.frame = newFrame;
```

but the height of the `UITextView` is bigger than its content. How can I solve my situation to obtain an height that will be the right one?

Have a nice day
Thank you very much

Comment: You can follow the following discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740382/ios-uitextview-set-height-equal-to-content-height/30619109#30619109

Answer (score 1):

Just use following code

```
[self.myTextView sizeToFit];
```

May be helpful for you.

> **NOTE :**  In iOS7 only **sizeToFit** wasn't working so you also need to write

```
[self.myTextView  sizeToFit];
[self.myTextView  layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Hi iPatel, thanks for your response. I've tried but unfortunally nothing happens. With my method if the original UITextView have 50px of height, the resized one will be 160px but is too big.